Embedded a Powershell Form inside Powershell console
I am trying to embed a PowerShell form into a PowerShell console, but the form either gets hidden or is only partially visible. Here is the code I used to embed the form into the console,
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Win32 {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
}
"@

# Get the console window handle directly
$consoleHandle = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle

# Set the parent of the form to the console window
[Win32]::SetParent($form.Handle, $consoleHandle) | Out-Null

# Show the form in a non-modal way
$form.Show()

# Keep the form running
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($form)



Have you added window handling, positioning etc?

yes, if i did not set the Console as parent, the form opens in a separate window and works fine, the problem is only when i embed the form inside console
